# opencv printing weird black images

Tags: c++, image, opencv

opencv imwrite is printing weird black(ish) images in my C++ code. An example code to read an image and then print it out is following:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cv::Mat input_image = cv::imread("input_image.tiff",0);
    cv::imwrite("output_image.tiff",input_image);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it as `` g++ -std=c++11 main.cc -o bin `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` ``

The input image and output image are as follows (should be the same):

Input Image      [image: Input Image]  Output Image     [image: Output image]

The image is being read correctly as I have checked it by accessing different pixel values.Therefore the problem is in imwrite.

Extra Info: The code was working fine in the beginning but suddenly changed its behavior, reinstalling opencv and its libraries doesn't help.

Can someone please tell what is wrong here,

Thanks

Comment: First make sure that input image you read is proper. Display it in a window. i.e. namedWindow("temp",input_image);
Also try saving in other formats such as BMP..

Comment: is that full code? looks like a bit like you used findContours (which modifies the input image!).

Comment: Yes this is the full code. The target was to see if imwrite was working. And yes it is working like as if I ran findContours in all the cases.

This started happening after SUSE update, so I wonder if it is a bug in openCV update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, I found out the error. The `libtiff` was broken and so tiff images were printing funny while other formats printed fine. Re installing `libtiff` and `tiff` fixed the error.